# ASP.NET MVC 4 Updates Causing Access Issues for MediaFormatters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom mediaformatter in my project that until ASP.NET MVC 4 updates last night was working fine. Now I get the following error from my webapi project. Any ideas? I have all of the dlls deployed in my bin folder so it shouldn't be using the system ones. I tried to change the signature of `CanReadType` from protected to public but I was given a build error.

> Derived method 'CanReadType' in type
>   'Project.MediaFormatters.JsonNetFormatter' from assembly 'Project,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' cannot reduce
>   access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing nupkg Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version:4.0.30506.0 should fix your problem. Seems you used very old version of System.Net.Http.Formatting. The MVC 4 update GACs the new version of System.Net.Http.Formatting which caused the runtime error. After you updated your mediaformatter, you got a compilation error, because your project still references the old version.

Comment: I have updated to the latest version and I had to make some changes but it appears to be working. Is there no way to make my project use the old dll version in the bin folder instead of the new GAC version?

Comment: one possible solution is to ungac the new System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll. But this may cause problem when you deploy your app onto a server with the security update installed.